# How do I change the origin point of the ".slideToggle" JQuery effect?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to create a "Log-in" button, that when clicked, will present an animated drop-down menu. The drop-down menu will contain three inputs, "username", "password" and "submit". The user will be able to subsequently click the "Log-in" button once again to retract the menu.

My current code:
http://jsfiddle.net/StacksOnStacksOverHoes/4uhKN/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>Home Page</title>
<!--Links to Temporary CSS page-->
<!-- Link to Google Jquery API -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Temporary JavaScript file--></script>
```

```
<body>
    <div class="site_header">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
            <a href="#">Products</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Surrogacy</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Applications</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Reporting Form</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Egg Donor</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Applications</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Reporting Form</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cryogenic Storage</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Applications</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Reporting Form</a></li> 
                        </ul>                         
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Infant Care</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Applications</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Reporting Form</a></li> 
                        </ul>                        
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Judgment or Asset<br>Liability</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Learn More</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Applications</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Reporting Form</a></li> 
                        </ul> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li><li>
            <a href="#">About Us</a></li><li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown item #01</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown item #02</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown item #03</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown item #04</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu #02</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">submenu item #01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">submenu item #02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">submenu item #03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">submenu item #04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- Nav End -->
        <div id="login_signup"><!-- Login and Sign up buttons START -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li><li id="loginnow">
            <a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    </div><!-- Login and Sign up button END -->
<div id="panel">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="loginputs" placeholder="Username">
        <br>
            <br>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" class="loginputs" placeholder="Password">
        <br>
            <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="loginputs">
</div>

</div>

JQuery:

    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#loginnow").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

CSS:

    /* Navigation Menu */
.site_header {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    /* Adds the transparent background */
    background-color: blue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline;
}
#nav {
    margin-left: 110px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size:20px;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #8D9FD0;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 13px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #444;
}
#nav > ul li:hover a {
    color: #FFF;
} 

/* Drop Down Menu */

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#FFF;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    min-width: 225px;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul li a,visited {
    color: blue;
}
#nav ul ul li:hover {
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

#nav ul ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul ul {
    margin: -52px 0 0 225px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
#nav ul ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #444;  
}
/* Log in and Sign Up */
#login_signup {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
#login_signup ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size:20px;
}
#login_signup ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#login_signup ul li:hover {
    background-color: #8D9FD0;
}
#login_signup ul li a, visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 13px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#login_signup ul li a:hover {
    color: #444;
}
#login_signup > ul li:hover a {}
h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}
.text a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* JQuery */
#panel {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    margin-top: 50px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: -1;
}
#panel
{
    float: right;
    width: 15%;
    display:none;
    margin-right: -190px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

End Result:
http://jsfiddle.net/StacksOnStacksOverHoes/4uhKN/embedded/result/

As of now when the "

" (list-item) is clicked. The form appears and stops exactly where I want it to. (The problem) is that the form visually appears to start the effect from the top of the screen, instead of the bottom of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because jQuery starts to animate from margin-top:0;

I think you need to use position:absolute to avoid wrong animation.

Here's example: http://jsfiddle.net/4uhKN/13/embedded/result/

That's my fix:

```
#panel {
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #CCC;
border: solid 1px #000;
width: 15%;
right: 190px;
top: 50px;
display: none;
z-index: -1;
position:absolute;
}
```

By the way, you will have to use media-screens or etc, because this fix may break mobile version of site.